# Display reason of failure on the Hudson Project page

Tags: plugins, hudson

I am new in Hudson. In my project it is required to display the reason of build failure on the hudson project page. Currenly while build failure we have to look at the console output to see exactly why the build failed.
Is there any possiblity to integrate the reason of build error into the project page display?

What I want instead of showing typical hudson build error message "Build #40 (Dec 18, 2009 8:02:38 AM)" it is required to display " Build #40 (Dec 18, 2009 8:02:38 AM) - Found 23 Medium severity issues."

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Description Setter Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Description+Setter+Plugin), it will allow you to set your run description based on a regex that runs over the build output - each run can have its own description.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the configuration of settings and regex you used?

Answer (score 0):

My approach...definetly not clean but it works:

You can parse the console output of Hudson...i mean the build progress...i search via regex for "Success" or "Failed" and typical Error messages and try to get the stacktrace...as i already said, not a nice and clean solution.